# Can we use Abel summation to show that $p(\pi(x))\sim x?$

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

**Motivation (can skip)**. It seems that $\phi(x), \psi(x)$ and functions that approximate $x$ in terms of the primes not exceeding $x$ all suffer from the same defect: they are inert between primes. So it seems like a reasonable exercise to show that, say, $\log\left(\sum_{p<x} e^p\right)$ or just $p(\pi(x))$ can be used to show the prime number theorem just as well as Chebyshev's functions above. One way would be to exhibit a relationship with $\pi(x)$ via Abel summation.

So using $\sum_{2\leq n\leq x } a(n)f(n) = A(n)f(n)-A(2)f(2)-\int_2^x A(x)f'(x)dx$ in which $a(n)$ is the index function over primes, if we can find a way to express $p_{\max}<x:=p(\pi(x))$ as $f(n)$ we are almost done, and we would have

$$p(\pi(x)) = \pi(n)f(n)-\pi(2)f(2)-\int_2^x \pi(x)f'(x)dx.  $$

> Can we find a $f(n)$ that allows us to use Abel summation in this case?

Of course $p(\pi(x))\sim x$ by the PNT, but that's not the question.

Comment: $p(n)$ is the $n$-th prime ? Then $p(\pi(x)) = x+\mathcal{O}(\pi(x))$ is equivalent to $p_n-p_{n+1} = \mathcal{O}(n)$

Comment: Looking at $p(\pi(x))-x$ and hence $p(\pi(x))$ will tell us something about $p_{n+1} - p_n$ (the prime gap) not about $\pi(x)$.

Comment: In other words you'll need to look at $\sum_{m < x} (m-p(\pi(m)))$

Comment: @user1952009: I don't doubt this-- but is there a reason in principle why the Abel summation won't work? I do understand it might be the wrong tool for the job. (back soon)

Comment: Why don't you work on a proof of the PNT ? It uses the summation by parts and Abel's formula many times. The objective to find a bound for $\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\ln x}$.

Comment: @user1952009: Well, it's only a question about the mechanics of the summation. Apostle uses this method to show that $\theta(s)\sim \pi(x)\log x$ and then $\theta(x)/x\sim 1 \to \log x \pi(x)/x \sim 1$ So it reduces showing $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$ to showing $\theta(x)\sim x.$ I didn't hope to do more than express the "greatest prime < x" in this way.

Comment: Doesn't work for what ?

Comment: @user1952009: Can we find $f$ in the equation above the yellow?

Comment: $\pi(x)$ appears from the summation by parts of $$\sum_{p \le  N} f(p) = \pi(N) f(N) + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \pi(n) (f(n)-f(n+1)) = \pi(N) f(N) + \int_1^N \pi(x) f'(x)dx$$
And $p(\pi(x)) = \sum_{p \le x} f(p)$ with $f(p_k) = p_{k}-p_{k-1}$, $f(n ) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @user1952009: Right, your expression for $p(\pi(x))$ was my starting point.

Comment: But the prime gaps are very irregular : we know almost nothing on $f(n)$. Except that $x-\sum_{n \le x} f(n) = x-p(\pi(x))$ is very small compared to $x$